# How to import Context from another module?

Tags: android, kotlin, module, build.gradle

The project has different modules. The one is that usecase module that I need to use Context inside it. When I added to context to constructor I can't import as `import android.content.Context` How can I use this? I tried to add these implementation to gradle.

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
```

When I added these, get this error

> Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1.

build.gradle(:usecase)

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':data')
    implementation project(path: ':entity')
    
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.2'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.akarnokd:rxjava3-retrofit-adapter:3.0.0'
}
```

UploadImageUseCase.kt

```
class UploadImageUseCase(
    private val requestCreationRepository: DocumentRepository,
    private val context: Context
) : UseCase<UploadImageAction, UploadImageResult> {

    override fun apply(upstream: Observable<UploadImageAction>): ObservableSource<UploadImageResult> {
        return upstream.flatMap { action ->
                val imageToFile = getImageFileFromUri(requireContext(), action.uri[0])
                val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestFile)
            requestCreationRepository.uploadImage(action).toObservable().map{ result ->
                result.fold(onSuccess = {
                    UploadImageResult.Successful(it.data!!)
                }, onFailure = {
                    UploadImageResult.Error(it)
                })
            }.startWithItem(UploadImageResult.Loading)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your module is a java library, which doesn't know about Android stuff. Therefore you have to make your module an Android library in order to get things like context, etc.

You have to change `id 'java-library'` into `id 'com.android.library'`

See the [documentation on creating an Android library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) for more information.